# REST API URL Structure Suggestion

Tags: .net, spring, spring-boot, rest, .net-core

I have 2 tables, MEMBERS and BOOKS in my SQL. So I want to let members ISSUE, RENEW and RETURN books. So all are PATCH request which updates a specific row in the table BOOK. But to do that I will have to include verb in the URL (ISSUE, RENEW or RETURN).
Is this a good url structure ? If bad, how should I approach this. [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fKtQ.jpg)

Here the constraints is 1 book only has one copy and a book has 1 author only

UPDATE: I changed my database schema now and moved some properties now to a different table called Transactions. Now can I use POST(issue book/add row in Transaction), PATCH(renew book/edit the due date of the transaction) and DELETE(return book/remove the row from Transaction).
Base URL remains same for all. Only methods change.

Base URL:`/api/members/{id}/books/{id}/`
[image]

Comment: In my view, your API structure could be.

Comment: API structure could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like below using PathVariable.

path:-- /v1/members/{id}

RequestBody:--

```
{
               member name="XXX", or email
                bookname="XXXX",
                status="issue/return/renew"
                 }
```

then you should valid Id and member name or ( id and email).

```
if(Success)
 read request and perform a/c that 
else
  throw member not found.
```

Comment: I updated my DB Schema. Is the logic in the Question's Update a good design ?

Comment: its good if you r ohk but I would suggest you to take an advantage of spring-boot , i mean  to say use OneToMany or ManyToMany concept. it will be easy for you only in future

Comment: And also accept the any of the above answer  if really helped you, so that others ppl easily will get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Formally speaking, an issue, a return, and renewal are called "verbal noun", so it is fine.
In any case, this API structure sounds fine.

If I were you I would check if maybe `POST` method is more appropriate for these kinds of operations.

Comment: I updated my DB Schema. Is the logic in the Question's Update a good design ?

Comment: yep, still looks OK for me.